# Сортировка объектов классов в разные массивы

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Есть Class1 и Class2. И есть класс, который должен создавать массивы из этих классов. Если передавать в конструктор объект неизвестного класса и там делать проверку, то возникает ошибка. Как это сделать?
Класс для создания массива:

```
 package com.company;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Generic {
 private ArrayList<Class1> arr1 = new ArrayList<>();
 private ArrayList<Class2> arr2 = new ArrayList<>();

 Generic(Object obj)
 {
     if (obj instanceof Class1)
     {
         this.arr1.add(obj); // Здесь ошибка возникает, хотя делаем проверку
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте класс так объявить: `public class Generic<T>` А конструктор так: `Generic(T obj)`. Не проверял, возможно не сработает/не скомпилируется.

Comment: Обобщениями пробывал, не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Следует явно привести тип переменной к классу:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Generic {
 private ArrayList<Class1> arr1 = new ArrayList<>();
 private ArrayList<Class2> arr2 = new ArrayList<>();

 Generic(Object obj)
 {
     if (obj instanceof Class1)
     {
         this.arr1.add((Class1)obj); // Здесь добавляем приведение типа
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: зачем приводить, если и так уже сравнили? это не дает ответ

Comment: @michael_best если кратко - `this.arr1.add(obj);` - здесь строка понятия не имеет о том, что ее где-то вверху "сравнили".